# React async/await blob() - Failed to execute "createObjectURL" on "URL"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, jsx

So I have an async function, I've been refactoring all my code to use async/await rather than the `.then()`. It's worked for every single function program wide except for this one blob. I really don't know why.

The OLD code that DOES work is here:

```js
  renderAvatar() {
    //This gets the avatar
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/get_avatar', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.username)
    }).then(res =>
      res.blob()
    ).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      const url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(res);
      const avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
      avatar.src = url;
    })
  }
```

This works fine, and I can still use this, but because everything else has been changed, I'd like to change this to await too. However, the following code throws errors at me, mostly about either URL being `null` or something else about promises.

```js
  async renderAvatar() {
    //This gets the avatar
    const data = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/get_avatar', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.username)
    })
    const avatarImage = await data.blob()
    console.log(avatarImage)
    const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(avatarImage);
    const avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
    avatar.src = url;
```

I've tried adding `await` to each of those const, doesn't change anything.

Error I get when saving:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot set property 'src' of null
Settings.renderAvatar
D:/Folders/Programming/React/notcord/app/src/Components/Settings.js:109
  106 |    const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  107 |    const url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(avatarImage);
  108 |    const avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
> 109 |    avatar.src = url;
      | ^  110 |  }
  111 | 
  112 |  handleFileChange = (e) => {
```

So if I add the "await" to the const url I still get this error AND this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
D:/Folders/Programming/React/notcord/app/src/App.js:29
  26 | ).then(res => {
  27 |   if(res !== "NotLoggedIn"){
  28 |     console.log(res)
> 29 |     this.setState({userLoggedIn: true})
     | ^  30 |   } else {
  31 |     console.log(res + "NOT WORKING")
  32 |   }
```

which doesn't make sense either.

Comment: at first glance, the code looks fine - is the console.log output consistent between the two versions?

Comment: Please add the actual error messages. Your refactoring looks correct.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I've posted the errors I get now